# SignalR OnConnected and OnDisconnected not firing

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm having trouble with OnConnected and OnDisconnected overrides in my Hub not firing.

For replication purposes, I've got a very simple Hub:

```
public class OnlineHub : Hub
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var a = 1;
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        return Clients.All.connected(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        return Clients.All.disconnected(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

And an aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $.connection.onlineHub.server.testMethod();
        });

        $.connection.onlineHub.server.connected = function (id, date) {
            $("#results").append("connected: " + id + " : " + date + "</br>");
        };

        $.connection.onlineHub.server.disconnected = function (id, date) {
            $("#results").append(("connected: " + id + " : " + date + "</br>");
        };

        $.connection.onlineHub.connection.start();
    });

</script>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 and signalR 1.0.0-alpha2.  The client side connected and disconnected methods are not being executed. And if I put a breakpoint in OnConnected or OnDisconnected, the breakpoints don't hit.

The connection is being made as my TestMethod calls ok and I'm getting a connectionId back from signalR's negotiate call.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your client handlers should probably look like this:

```
$.connection.onlineHub.client.connected = function(){...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in this case, the way I'm doing it is correct as it's not a handler as such, but a definition of a method that the server can call. Thanks anyway though. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm right! https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client

Comment: It does not work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157099/signalr2-onconnected-not-working-as-per-documentation

Answer (score 9):

It also turns out that on a script you need to define at least one client callback for events to be raised on the hub. Be careful with this when expected OnConnected and OnDisconnected to be called.

Comment: Also take a look at this https://coderwall.com/p/5oykeq/be-careful-about-ondisconnected-when-using-signalr

Comment: also take care, that the client-callback methods are defined before $.connection.hub.start() is called

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  I was calling the methods on the server object rather than the client:

```
$.connection.onlineHub.server.connected = function (id, date) {
        $("#results").append("connected: " + id + " : " + date + "</br>");
    };

    $.connection.onlineHub.server.disconnected = function (id, date) {
        $("#results").append(("connected: " + id + " : " + date + "</br>");
    };
```

should be

```
$.connection.onlineHub.client.connected = function (id, date) {
        $("#results").append("connected: " + id + " : " + date + "</br>");
    };

    $.connection.onlineHub.client.disconnected = function (id, date) {
        $("#results").append(("connected: " + id + " : " + date + "</br>");
    };
```

So it looks like if signalR hasn't got anything defined for the task within the OnDisconnected or OnConnected, then they don't get fired.  Which makes sense.

Comment: You should mark @Duncan's answer as good, since he was right !

Comment: The right answer is @Duncan's, since he posted it like half an hour earlier!

Comment: Yes, thank you @Matei_Radu for chiming in in such a prompt fashion on a 3+ year old question. Where would this site be without you!?

Comment: I just thought that his answer deserved to be marked accordingly, if I upset you in any way it wasn't my intention, but still...:)

Comment: It is marked accordingly. And has been since Jan 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this code. when put it back, started working

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {               
    //chat.server.sendMessageToBackend($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());                 
});
```