# SignalR2 OnConnected not working as per documentation

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-2

Below is the code I wrote for `SignalR` implementation based on [ASP.Net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy) and I use manual proxy creation method. I Could see only negotiate happening and received a Connection id.

I can't see `OnConnected` method in my hub gets executed when I start connection. According to the note section in the document I have attached event handler before I call start method

**SignalR Hub**

```
public class MyTestHub: Hub
{
    private static Dictionary<int, List<string>> userConnections 
                                                     = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        RegisterUserConnectionInMap();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
     app.Map(
           "/signalr",
            map =>
            {
              var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true};
              map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

**Javascript Client Code**

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('MyTestHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(userName:any, message:any) {
    console.log(userName + ' ' + message);
});
connection.start()
.done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
.fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
```

[Note section in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy)

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the `start` method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   `start` method. One reason for this is that there can be many Hubs in an
>   application, but you wouldn't want to trigger the `OnConnected` event on
>   every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them. When the
>   connection is established, the presence of a client method on a Hub's
>   proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the `OnConnected` event. If you
>   don't register any event handlers before calling the `start` method, you
>   will be able to invoke methods on the Hub, but the Hub's `OnConnected`
>   method won't be called and no client methods will be invoked from the
>   server.

I could not figure out what I miss for past two days.

**UPDATE**:

Even I tried with auto generated proxy class by including `<script src="~/SignalR/hubs"` with the following client code. **Still OnConnected Not fired**

```
var contosoChatHubProxy = $.connection.myTestHub;
contosoChatHubProxy.client.addContosoChatMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
    console.log(userName + ' ' + message);
};
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
```

Console Log after connectton

[image]

Comment: Can you show the whole client script? Do you have any browser console output?

Comment: @Tester attached screenshot

Comment: Have you found solution yet?

Comment: @NguyenTran please see my answer below. Sorry for delay

Answer (score 1):

I have ended with the below solution. Hope it will help some one.

```
declare var $: any;

@Injectable()
export class CityChangeNotifier {

constructor(private appService: AppService, private router: Router) {
    this.connection = $.hubConnection();
    this.CityChangeHub = this.connection.createHubProxy('CityChangeNotificationHub');
    this.CityChangeHub
        .on('CityUpdatedByServer', (newLocation:any, connectionId:string) => this.onCityUpdatedByServer(newLocation, connectionId));
    this.connection.transportConnectTimeout = 10000;
    this.startConnection();  
 }

private startConnection(): void {
    let that = this;
    this.connection.start()
        .done((connection: any) => { that.connectionId = connection.id; })
        .fail(() => { });  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! I missed this line `this.CityChangeHub
        .on('CityUpdatedByServer', (newLocation:any, connectionId:string) => this.onCityUpdatedByServer(newLocation, connectionId));`